# Returning values from ArrayList Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to return an array of values. I did this and managed to retrieved the values  in JSONService. How do I retrieve the array of values in my method **updateUI** in OneMap.Java ? I got an nullexception error at the first line of updateUI()

OneMap.java

```
public class OneMap extends Activity implements OnSingleTapListener
{
    private Map map=null;
    private ArrayList<Map> list = null; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      loadData();
    }
    private void loadData() {
       new GetCoordinationsDetailsTask().execute();
    }
   private class GetCoordinationsDetailsTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    };

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        list=JSONService.getLocationList();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        updateUI();
    }
}

private void updateUI() {
    String name=map.getName();
    String region=map.getRegion();
    String iconurl=map.getIconURL();
    String address=map.getAddress();
    String contactno=map.getContactNo();
    String operatinghrs=map.getOperatingHrs();
    String coordinates=map.getCoordinates();
```

JSONService.java

```
public static ArrayList<Map> getLocationList() {
    String url = second_URL + "storelocator.php";
    String method = GET;
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONObject result = makeHttpRequest(url, method, params);

    try {
        Log.d("result",result.toString());
        if (result.getInt("success") == 1) {
            JSONArray jLocationList = result.getJSONArray("store_list");
            ArrayList<Map> list = new ArrayList<Map>();

            int count = jLocationList.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                JSONObject jlocation = jLocationList.getJSONObject(i);
                String LocationName=jlocation.getString("mall");
                String region=jlocation.getString("region");
                String iconURL=jlocation.getString("image");
                String address=jlocation.getString("address");
                String telephone=jlocation.getString("contact");
                String operatinghrs=jlocation.getString("Operating");
                String coordinates=jlocation.getString("coordinates");
                Map location= new Map(LocationName,region,iconURL,address,telephone,operatinghrs,coordinates);
                //list.add(location);
            }
            return list;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Map.java

```
public class Map {

private String name=null;
private String region=null;
private String iconURL=null;
private String address=null;
private String contactNo=null;
private String operatinghrs=null;
private String coordinates=null;


public Map(String name,String region,String iconURL,String address, String contactNo, String operatinghrs,String coordinates)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.region=region;
    this.iconURL=iconURL;
    this.address=address;
    this.contactNo=contactNo;
    this.operatinghrs=operatinghrs;
    this.coordinates=coordinates;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public String getRegion()
{
    return region;
}
public String getIconURL()
{
    return iconURL;
}
public String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}
public String getContactNo()
{
    return contactNo;
}
public String getOperatingHrs()
{
    return operatinghrs;
}
public String getCoordinates()
{
    return coordinates;
}
}
```

Comment: create an empty constructor for map, in addition to your Map class and instantiate it with the empty constructor one

Answer (score 1):

You forget to create instance of Map in OneMap

Comment: OneMap.java to ----- protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      map=new Map();
    }

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute` calls `updateUI`, that uses the map object which was not initialized. On the other hand, your `JSONService.getLocationList` returns an `ArrayList<Map>`. You could get on element from this ArrayList in order to fill up  the UI.

Comment: How do I peek on element from the ArrayList?

Comment: you could use the `get(int index)` method